# Android - detect if it is called from react native/xamarin/flutter etc

Tags: android, flutter, react-native

I'm building an Android SDK and our clients might call the SDK from cross platform plugins such as react native/flutter/xamarin.

Is it possible to detect whether the current SDK is called from a native Android app or one of these plugins?

On iOS it's possible to tell this by attempting to create a platform specific class reflectively and check its nullability - e.g `NSClassFromString("RCTBridge")`

Comment: i guess for react native you might have to provide a bridge, which would mean you provide native methods, so if those methods are called than it's RN. not sure about the xamarin or flutter

Comment: If you are providing only native sdk, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using reflection to check for `com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule` which is a class that will not be proguard-ed in a stock react native app.